# How to edit request url in service worker?

Tags: javascript, caching, request, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm using cache first caching strategy for my pwa, for every GET request I first look if that request exists in cache, if it does I return it and update the cache.

The problem is that users can switch between multiple projects, so when they switch to another project,
the first time they open some url, they get the stuff from previous project if it exists in cache.

My solution is to try to add GET parametar ?project=projectId(project=2 for example) in the service worker, so each project would have its own version of the request saved in the cache.
I wanted to concatinate project id to the event.request.url, but I've read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/url) that it is read only.

After doing that, hopefully I would have urls like this in cache:

> Instead of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions
>
> I would have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?project=1
>
> And: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?project=2

So I would get questions from the project I'm on, instead of just getting questions from previous project is /questions is saved in cache already.

Is there a way to edit request url in service worker?

My service worker code:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  
  const url = new URL(event.request.clone().url);
  if (event.request.clone().method === 'POST') {
      // update project id in service worker when it's changed
      if(url.pathname.indexOf('/project/') != -1 ) {
            // update user data on project switch
            let splitUrl = url.pathname.split('/');
            if (splitUrl[2] && !isNaN(splitUrl[2])) {
                console.log( user );
                setTimeout(function() {
                  fetchUserData();
                  console.log( user );
                }, 1000);
            }
       }  
       // do other unrelated stuff to post requests
       .....
  } else { // HANDLE GET REQUESTS
      // ideally,here I would be able to do something like this:
      if(user.project_id !== 'undefined') {
          event.request.url = event.request.url + '?project=' + user.project_id;
      }

      event.respondWith(async function () {
        const cache = await caches.open('CACHE_NAME')

        const cachedResponsePromise = await cache.match(event.request.clone())
        const networkResponsePromise = fetch(event.request.clone())
        if (event.request.clone().url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {
          event.waitUntil(async function () {
            const networkResponse = await networkResponsePromise.catch(function(err) {
              console.log( 'CACHE' );
              // return caches.match(event.request);
              return caches.match(event.request).then(function(result) {
                  // If no match, result will be undefined
                  if (result) {
                       return result;
                  } else {
                       return caches.open('static_cache')
                         .then((cache) => {
                             return caches.match('/offline.html');
                       });
                  }
             });
            });
            await cache.put(event.request.clone(), networkResponse.clone())
          }())
        }
       
        // news and single photos should be network first       
        if (url.pathname.indexOf("news") > -1 || url.pathname.indexOf("/photos/") > -1) {
            return networkResponsePromise || cachedResponsePromise;  
        }
        return cachedResponsePromise || networkResponsePromise;
      }())
      
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use any URL as a cache key when reading/writing to the Cache Storage API. When writing to the cache via [`put()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/put), for instance, you can pass in a string representing the URL you'd like to use as the first parameter:

```
// You're currently using:
await cache.put(event.request.clone(), networkResponse.clone())

// Instead, you could use:
await cache.put(event.request.url + '?project=' + someProjectId, networkResponse.clone())
```

But I think a better approach that would accomplish what you're after is to use different cache names for each project, and then within each of those differently-named caches you would not have to worry about modifying the cache keys to avoid collisions.

```
// You're currently using:
const cache = await caches.open('CACHE_NAME')

// Instead, you could use:
const cache = await caches.open('CACHE_NAME' + someProjectId)
```

(I'm assuming that you have some reliable way of figuring out what the correct someProjectId value should be inside of the service worker, based on which client is making the incoming request.)